# Need help creating subdirectories to store files with dates in them

Tags: bash, shell-script, redhat-enterprise-linux, rhel-7

New to this forum, however not new to RHEL or scripting. However this one is a bit annoying me. I have the following files:

```
2019-05-01-00.34.00.msg 
2019-05-02-00.36.00.msg
2019-06-14-01.38.00.msg
```

I want to store them in directories like this:

```
/2019/05/01/<Filename>
/2019/05/02/<Filename>
/2019/06/14/<Filename>
```

I would like to keep the current file name as well when placing them in the directories. Also, I would like to do this with bash.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Cross-posted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/546977/108618) and [there](https://askubuntu.com/q/1181280/693277). Please see [*Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was cross-posted to two other SE sites. This is discouraged in general. The question shows no research effort and has been answered elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way could be using the combination of **find**,**awk** and **xargs**, just replace  where the *.msg files exist :

```
#!/bin/bash
files="$(find <your_directory> -type f -name '*.msg' | sed 's#.*/##')"
echo "$files" | awk -F '-' '/1/ {print $1"/"$2"/"$3"/"}' | xargs -I {} mkdir -p {}
echo "$files" | awk -F '-' '/1/ {print $1"/"$2"/"$3"/" $0}' | xargs -I {} touch {}
```

Results :

```
2019/05/01/2019-05-01-00.34.00.msg
2019/05/02/2019-05-02-00.36.00.msg
2019/06/14/2019-06-14-01.38.00.msg
```